# Does a C++ standard library have to be written in C or assembly?

Tags: c++, implementation, standard-library

Is it possible to write the complete C++ standard library (including STL of course, but self-contained, only internal dependencies) using only C++? I would imagine containers and `<cstdlib>` functionality would be doable in terms of `char`s, bitshifts, and for loops and other byte fancy things, but stuff like exceptions and perhaps `std::cout` and `std::cin` seem hard to me without a dependency to begin with. Let's say there is a set of OS functions available, that are completely implemented in assembly (to avoid any C contamination).

I'm assuming the compiler understands everything from classes and virtual functions to templates and function overloading, these are language level things and have no place in a library IMHO.

If this has been asked before or is a trivially stupid question, please forgive me. I'm not trying to start a C<->C++ war here, just trying to figure out the limitations of implementing a beast such as the Standard library...

Thanks!

Comment: Is your C++ compiler written in C?

Comment: Let's assume that's either statically linked C++ (no <cstdlib> stuff used in the library/compiler) created from any previously present C++ compiler (that might have been written in C), or one written entirely in assembly. Just to take out all C influence that might sneak in ;-)

Comment: You can implement most languages using the language you're implementing so long as a compiler already exists.  A good example, along with some interesting side effects, are documented in the article "Reflections of Trusting Trust": http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/ken/trust.html

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? I assume that most implementations *are* straight C++.

Comment: @meagar: there's a difference between all the templated functionality and the more basic functions nested deeper in the implementation and needed by the higher level template functionality...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since pretty much anything written in C can be rewritten fairly easily in C++, you're asking whether assembly code is needed, and the answer is generally no.

Unless we're talking about embedded programming, operating systems have all the necessary file and I/O functionality available through system calls, usually (nowadays) in C format.  The library needs to call them, likely through `extern "C"{ ... }` declarations.  The operating system functions are not considered part of the C++ library, and typically aren't exact matches to anything defined in the C++ Standard.

To implement a C++ standard library, you would need to be familiar with the language itself, know the OS calls you're going to use, and have the algorithms you're going to use.  At that point, it's a relatively straightforward matter of writing the software.

Comment: Thanks. Why is there no "C++ based OS"? What I mean is an OS that maps quite transparently on the C++ standard libary functions, like as you say, most OSes map quite well in C functionality. Especially with C++0x that is a very viable combination IMO, and before it might have needed boost quite heavily, but still, how come?

Comment: @rubenv: Actually, there are quite a few "C++ based OS" around.

Comment: @Nemanja: could you give an example? I think most POSIX-like environments are pretty C-oriented on a system level (linux and Mac OS), and so is Windows...

Comment: @rubenvb: Yes, the Unix is pretty much all C. Windows, however has most user-mode code written in C++. Symbian is all C++, and also BlackBerry OS (exept for the API, which is Java). BeOS is another relativelly popular OS written completely in C++.

Comment: @Nemanja: ah didn't know that about Symbian, Blackberry OS and BeOS. But looking at the Win32 API, that's very much C style... no templates or classes anywhere, only `struct`s and `char*`s (and all ugly typedefs/defines thereof)

Comment: @rubenvb:  Partly tradition, and because C is good enough.  Partly, I'd imagine, because there's something of a de facto C ABI that tons of other languages can use, and there isn't one for C++, since C++ calls can be much more complicated.  Therefore, the OS API at least will consist of C-style functions.

Comment: @rubienv: A large part of Windows API is obviously C++: look at Windows Shell, GDI+, DirectX...

Comment: @Nemanja: ah, now I see, those are the parts I would use a platform abstraction for, hence my ignorance. Learning more every day!

Comment: "A large part of Windows API is obviously C++" -- technically many of the APIs are COM interfaces, which can be accessed in C or assembly with an explicit "this" parameter (that becomes quickly annoying). Not that there would be an advantageous reason to stay in C, but you could if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 3):

First thing, it doesn't matter if it's C, C++, or D. Any compilable programming language at the end gives you (mostly) the same assembly object file.

Second thing, STL is written in C++, you cannot write C++ library in C or any other language (well, you can but I assume, that we're talking on reasonable solutions). You cannot implement STL containers in C, because the're strongly use templates.

GCC generate really nice output in asm for exceptions now. I recommend to read about C++ ABI (if you're interested in it).

C++ compiler understands all C++ specific features really nice nowadays. Thanks to really advanced code analysis and optimizations, it's able to produce fast executables (see first paragraph).

I hope that I've at least partly answered your question.

Comment: Don't bother spending too much time on the ABI its not really relevant as it is not standardized and each compiler is free to use any ABI they like.

Comment: @Martin York: However it's very good way to understand how specific features work (exceptions, unwinding stack, etc.) and be truly aware, why they may cause performance decrease.

Comment: I disagree. Unless you are a compiler writer then the information is mostly noise to the average developer.

Answer (score 2):

The only piece of C++ that needs assembly is the exception handling. I suppose that it might be doable in C++ if there exist libraries to handle the necessary register and stack management.

Of course, those libraries would then include assembly.  There just isn't any other way to do direct register management.

Answer (score 1):

The STL is very heavily reliant on `#include`ed header files. Those pretty much have to be C++.

Anything that isn't in one of those header files though could in theory be implemented in C, Ada, Assembly, or the other systems-programming language of your choice. However, you'd probably have to be maintaining two interfaces if you don't make at least the top layer C++.